# Include a $user.txt in php

Tags: php, forms, variables, include

i have a little problem, that i dont know how to solve.. i'm new with that kind of php stuff.
How can I include a file, named `$user` + extension `.txt` (`$user.txt`), that comes with that form:

```
<form action="status.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="USER" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="Submit" />
</form>
```

And, the results (incluiding the file) comes in the same page.

Comment: did you try include('filename');

Comment: Please note that this approach requires extra caution since it's not a big deal for a user to include whatever he wants (even if you have client-side verification). Without additional server-side restrictions every user will be able to access any txt-document on the host (not necessarily in only one folder). Example: '../secret_folder/passwords', etc.

Comment: +1 to that. User input can very easily go wrong, and file uploads are particularly tricky. Sorry for the wall of text I wrote, but even after such an extensive answer I feel like I've left out some important things behind ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

```
if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
    include($_POST['user'].".txt");      
}
```

Comment: will you provide a reason for downvote. Because I don think the OP asked to upload a file and include it from the code. Its clear from the question above. Then what is it that you are downvoting for?

Comment: Now I see the question is unclear about the file being sent "And the results (including the file) comes in the same page" (I thought the results of sending the form). I also see it isn't clear either about the origin of the file: "comes with the form" (I understood comes with the form on the request, along with the form input data). Either way, you provided the answer the OP was looking for and I didn't downvote it. In fact, you have my upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is an simple example. all in one file.

#### status.php

```
<?php
//path/to/status.php

/**
* Process user input.
* Return content to display 
* @return Array 
*/
function process_form(){

    //initialize variables
    //displayed or not the $content. Default is false
    $view_result = false;
    //content to display. Default is an empty string
    $content = ''; 

    //it verifies if the form has been sent
    if(isset($_POST['submit_form']) && $_POST['submit_form']=='submit'){

        //Set $view_result = true to display the message back
        $view_result = true;

        //if no file has been sent in form
        if($_FILES['user_file']['error'] == 4){
            return array('view_result'=>$view_result, 'content'=>'file not sent');}

        //other errors
        if($_FILES['user_file']['error'] != 0){
            return array('view_result'=>$view_result, 'content'=>'An error occurred');}

        //verified whether it is a txt file type
        if($_FILES['user_file']['type'] != 'text/plain'){
            return array('view_result'=>$view_result, 'content'=>'Invalid File Format');}

        //check size file
        if($_FILES['user_file']['size'] > 300){ //the size in bytes
            return array('view_result'=>$view_result, 'content'=>'File exceeds the maximum size allowed');}


        //make sure you have created the **uploads/** directory
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['user_file']['name'])){
            $content = file_get_contents('uploads/'.$_FILES['user_file']['name']);
            //you can manipulate $content if necessary
            return array('view_result'=>$view_result, 'content'=>$content);
        }
    }
    else{ return array('view_result'=>$view_result, 'content'=>$content); }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User form with an attached file</title>
</head>
<body>

   <!--If the form has been sent-->
   <?php
    //get data and then display
    $process = process_form();
    if($process['view_result']){
    ?>
    <div id="result">
        <p><?=$_POST['user_name']?></p>
        <p>
            <pre><?= $process['content'] ?></pre>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <!--form section-->
    <form id="user_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="user_name" value="Jane Doe" placeholder="Enter user name"/><br/>
        <input type="file" name="user_file"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

you can text script with JaneDoe.txt.

#### JaneDoe.txt

```
user_first_name  : Jane
user_last_name   : Doe
user_id     : #789AE0B1
```

Comment: Can you please add comments ?